# When to use Akka's FSM

Tags: java, akka, fsm

I am looking for use cases when Akka's FSM feature is most useful. I am working on an example where an objects goes through various states asynchronously , these states are saved in the database and are changes with only a single actor. Is this a good example?

Is there any doc other than official akka docs to understand this better?

Answer (score 0):

It might help you.

[Akka Notes - Finite State Machines - 1](http://rerun.me/2016/05/21/akka-notes-finite-state-machines-1/)

[Akka Notes - Finite State Machines - 2](http://rerun.me/2016/05/22/akka-notes-finite-state-machines-2/)

The best use i have seen of it when there is need to implement throttling mechanism. For that you can refer my [blog](https://blog.knoldus.com/2018/01/22/how-to-throttle-messages-using-akka-fsm/)

Comment: thanks I'll take a loook, but is the FSM framework design for acto states or data states?

Comment: Your welcome. It is about actor states. And according to actor states data states change too.

Comment: I am still not sure if it applies to my usecase though